# Unable to pass data from Servlet to Android

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I am new to Android. Got a few question regarding the pass back data from Servlet to Android.

So here is my code at servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String action = request.getParameter("action");
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("GetAllGame")) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = db
                .getStatement("SELECT * FROM game");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            JSONObject gameInfo = new JSONObject();
            gameInfo.put("gameID", result.getString("gameID"));
            gameInfo.put("gameVenue", result.getString("venueID"));
            gameInfo.put("gameDate", result.getString("date"));
            gameInfo.put("gameCapacity",
                    result.getString("gameCapacity"));
            gameInfo.put("gameCredit",
                    result.getString("gameCredit"));
            gameInfo.put("gameBy", result.getString("gameBy"));
            gameInfo.put("gameStart", result.getString("gameStart"));
            gameInfo.put("gameEnd", result.getString("gameEnd"));
            jsonArray.put(gameInfo);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    out.println(jsonArray.toString());
    System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
    out.write(jsonArray.toString());
    out.flush();
}
```

When I launch the servlet, it pop out a website with texts like:

TODO write content
Click here to go My Servlet

Sorry as I am still new and unable to post picture. And when I execute the URL on computer such as `http://localhost:8080/WebService/MyServlet?action=GetAllGame` , at the console of GlassFish server tab, it did actually print out all the data but nothing is showing on the pop out website.

However, when I ping my phone to my computer and trying to grab the data from my phone, the same thing happens, the data is showing at the console but not on the website in phone. I thought it should be shown on with some json formatted data?

So I thought it was okay until when I implement it into my Android apps, and it is stating that the json passing back from servlet is empty. Any ideas?

What I meant is the data is just printing out from my computer but not actually return back to Android.